# mysql connection in sleep status but client never receives data and times out

Tags: mysql

We have an important program written in Java which keeps a persistant connection to a mysql-database. Starting this monday, a lot of our customers reports problems when starting the program, as it first loads a long customer list from the database. What really puzzels us is that we get the error on some computers, but not on others, even in our own office!
What happens is, the method getCustomers is called. I can then in the mysql console see that the select query gets processed with status "writing to net". Then the connection goes back to "sleep" status after some seconds, Normally 5-10-15 depending on the number of rows.
On some computers everything is now ok, but on others, even though the connection went back to "sleep" status on the server, nothing happens on the client side, until after 2 minutes the loading is aborted by the normal 2-minute-timeout and the following exception is thrown:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:105)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:148)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1899)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:481)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.serverExecute(ServerPreparedStatement.java:1133)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ServerPreparedStatement.java:670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1024)
at pos.LocalDBComm.getCustomers(LocalDBComm.java:4542)
```

We have tried restarting the mysql service, disabling avira real-time mode etc, but nothing seems to help. We are really stuck, and would appreciate some insight into why this error just started occuring, and why it only affects some computers. Since we have 2 computers in the same office where the first one works every time and the second one never works, I guess it cannot be due to firewall settings either. It is only the long query that is affected, small queries seems to work as before.

Update:
Amazingly, after half a day of this bug, Things suddenly started working again. I am perplexed and at a loss to know how it suddenly started working again.
ANYWAY, the next day it did NOT work anymore! The query just hangs as before. This is really VERY strange. It goes from working to not working without anyone having done anything.

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL server timeout can occur for many reasons, but happens most often when a command is sent to MySQL over a closed connection. The connection could have been closed by the MySQL server because of an idle-timeout; however, in most cases it is caused by either an application bug, a network timeout issue.

I would check the following

1. Search the logs to see if there are any indications af a failing query
2. Check the connections on your server

   mysqladmin processlist | grep database-name
3. Check your server confiuration

   mysql> SHOW VARIABLES;
4. Check your datasource to ensure you have the correct number of connections

   max-connections="100"
   min-connections="5"
   inactivity-timeout="200"

Comment: We have done nothing to the server configuration. Last week everything worked, this monday it did not (on some computers). Nothing has been restarted this weekend. (But we tried restarting mysql after the bug was discovered). As I explained, the connection goes to sleep status when running "show processlist", but nothing happens on the client side before 2 minutes have passed, as defined on our connection string: &socketTimeout=120000 It is only long queries that are affected, and connections are below max-connections.

Comment: Sometimes setting a long timeout is not ideal as if you have a failing query you will run out of connections faster as they take longer to timeout. There is not enough information so you will have to combe the server and client logs looking for clues. Check that there are enough connections when the query is made and their remain enough connections until it times out. Restart and tail the logs, look at http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: There are allways enough connections. As I wrote, each program that starts has a persistant connection. Therefore we will not run out of connections, as we reuse the old one, that worked on previous queries, but when it is used to load the customer list, it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

We have published a workaround now that limits our big queries by using the mysql LIMIT keyword, so that we only read 5000 rows at a time. This seems to work. But we have run this program on countless computers for about 8 years now without ever before encountering this behaviour, and since running 12 queries with LIMIT to obtain 60000 rows of data only takes about 15 seconds or less, there is no reason why the full query should hang and then time out after 2 minutes, especially since the query is finished "writing to net" and goes to status "sleep" in mysql console after only some seconds. And why does it work as before on some computers and not on others? It is almost as if the most plausible explanation is that the query data is intercepted ny NSA or another corporation for "analyzis" on certain hours of the day on certain infected computers if the data is over a certain size...

Answer (score 0):

You can tray to keep a live your connection, i found this code, i hope this help you.

```
public static final String DATABASE_USER = "user";
public static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String MYSQL_AUTO_RECONNECT = "autoReconnect";
public static final String MYSQL_MAX_RECONNECTS = "maxReconnects";

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
     String driver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";

     Class.forName(driver);
     String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/tiger";
     String dbUsername = "root";
     String dbPassword = "root";

     java.util.Properties connProperties = new java.util.Properties();
     connProperties.put(DATABASE_USER, dbUsername);
     connProperties.put(DATABASE_PASSWORD, dbPassword);

     connProperties.put(MYSQL_AUTO_RECONNECT, "true");

     connProperties.put(MYSQL_MAX_RECONNECTS, "4");
     return DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, connProperties);
}
```